# JqGrid Erro ao salvar campo data via Datepicker

Tags: jqgrid, datepicker

Estou com um problema que ao salvar um campo via datepicker, o mesmo ao invés de enviar o valor, envia o mesmo via input, este caso é apenas nos casos em que o botão enter não é pressionado.

```
$(function () {

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'odo_ctd0004b.asp',
        mtype: 'GET',
        ...
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['Operadora', 'Nº Remessa', 'Ref. Anterior', 'Situação do Físico', 'Situação Remessa', 'Dt. Recebimento', 'Dt. Postagem', 'Qtd Guias', 'Val. Apresentado', 'COD_TS_NR', 'COD_OPERADORA'],
        colModel:[{name:'NOM_OPERADORA',                index:'NOM_OPERADORA'               , width:120, align:"left"},
                  {name:'NUM_GRD',                      index:'NUM_GRD'                     , width:100, align:"center"},
                  {name:'MES_ANO_REF_ANTERIOR',         index:'MES_ANO_REF_ANTERIOR'        , width:130, align:"center"},
                  {name:'NOME_SITUACAO_FISICO',         index:'NOME_SITUACAO_FISICO'        , width:180, align:"left"},
                  {name:'NOME_SITUACAO_REMESSA',        index:'NOME_SITUACAO_REMESSA'       , width:180, align:"left"},
                  {name:'DATA_RECEBIMENTO',             index:'DATA_RECEBIMENTO'            , width:150, align:"center", editable: true, sorttype:"date"},
                  {name:'DT_POSTAGEM',                  index:'DT_POSTAGEM'                 , width:150, align:"center", editable: true, sorttype:"date"},
                  {name:'QTD_CONTAS',                   index:'QTD_CONTAS'                  , width:100, align:"right"},
                  {name:'VAL_APRESENTADO',              index:'VAL_APRESENTADO'             , width:150, align:"right"},
                  {name:'COD_TS_NR',                    index:'COD_TS_NR'                   , hidden: true },
                  {name:'COD_OPERADORA',                index:'COD_OPERADORA'               , hidden: true }
                ],              

        onSelectRow: function(id, rowid){
            if(id && id!=lastsel){
                jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('saveRow',rowid); //Tem que estar saveRow senão retorna ao valor original
                jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,pickdates);
                lastsel=id;
            }           
        },
        ... 
        rowList: [50, 100, 150],            
        recordtext: "Vendo {0} - {1} de {2}",
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}); 

});
```

Imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: poderia colocar a imagem aqui?

Comment: Não possuo reputação para o mesmo, mas postei a imagem no post, segue o link http://s24.postimg.org/7zh3b4q9x/erri_Jqgrid.png

Comment: não sabia de tal restrição, adicionei para ficar mais fácil

Comment: A tudo bem, mas postei ela acima. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem pessoal, para realizar o ajuste eu alterei o grid para edição de células e apliquei os ajustes das células para a função `aftereditcell()`, pois quando estava gerando o XML da forma  anterior o objeto ainda não estava finalizado e por isso foi criado no formato de input.