# Simular uma tecla do teclado ao perder o foco

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço uma simulação de uma tecla do teclado (no meu caso a tecla enter), mas no caso em Jquery.

Mas a mesma tem que simular ao sair de um input por exemplo.

Segue [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5514/jqgrid-erro-ao-salvar-campo-data-via-datepicker) com um outro post meu que tem imagens relacionada.

Comment: o que quer dizer com "simular" ?

Comment: porque não dispara o que tiver que disparar no enter tambem na perda de foco do campo ?

Comment: Bem vou explicar o que quero fazer, estou trabalhando com Jqgrid, e quando o usuário esta realizando uma edição (inline) o cambo fica habilitado e ele salva as informações ao pressionar a tecla Enter, neste caso gostaria de que quando o usuário perder o foco do campo, fosse simulado a tecla Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o evento [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) no elemento que dispara o "Enter" ao perder o foco. E na captura do evento, dispare um evento [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) com informações próprias através do método [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Mais ou menos assim:

```
foo.blur(function () {
    var keypress = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    keypress.which = 13; // 13 é o codigo da tecla Enter
    keypress.keyCode = 13; // vide linha acima
    $(this).trigger(keypress);
});
```

Note que o código acima simula o Enter pressionado no mesmo componente que perdeu o foco. Você pode usar outro componente, de acordo com sua necessidade ;)

Comment: No caro o "foo" seria o meu objeto? Estou testando aqui e retorno logo.

Comment: Sim. `foo` é um elemento qualquer, que você já obteve via jQuery. Em exemplos de código, é normal usarmos os nomes *foo* e *bar* para as variáveis ;)

Comment: Obrigado, estou testando aqui e já retorno.

Comment: Não consegui simular a tecla, não sei se é pelo fato de eu estar usando o JqGrid e não funcionar, mas realizei uma função que faz gerae o que eu preciso ao perder o foco no objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível simular uma tecla em específico, somente um evento.

Talvez se puder ser mais específico com a sua necessidade possam haver outras soluções.

Caso queira disparar uma função tanto ao pressionar enter quando ao tirar o foco do campo (Caso resolva), algo assim pode ajudar:

```
$('#id-do-seu-campo').on('keypress blur', function(event) {

    if((event.type == 'keypress' && event.keyCode == 13) || event.type == 'blur') {

        // Aqui você faz o quer que aconteça no pressionar do enter.

    }

});
```

Comment: Bem, estou utilizando Jqgrid e ele salva as informações no servidor quando é pressionado a tecla enter, senão ao invés de enviar a informação ao servidor ele envia o objeto completo, conforme o link que eu mesmo publiquei http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5514/jqgrid-erro-ao-salvar-campo-data-via-datepicker

Comment: Acho que essa resposta ficaria melhor como um comentário...

Comment: Bem vou explicar o que quero fazer, estou trabalhando com Jqgrid, e quando o usuário esta realizando uma edição (inline) o cambo fica habilitado e ele salva as informações ao pressionar a tecla Enter, neste caso gostaria de que quando o usuário perder o foco do campo, fosse simulado a tecla Enter

Comment: O que pretendo fazer é o mesmo que uma classe robot faz no java, mas fazendo o jquery ter o controle do teclado, no caso apenas da tecla enter

Comment: Se eu entendi melhor, creio que você possa delegar eventos `blur` e `keyup`, e dentro de keyup verificar se `event.keyCode` é igual a 13, que corresponde a tecla enter, se você delegar os dois eventos e na função fazer a ação que deseja creio que terá o mesmo efeito e não precisaria "simular" uma tecla...

Comment: Diego, você teria um exemplo? vou pesquisar sobre esses eventos.

Comment: Posso tentar fazer, algo, você esta usando jQuery no seu projeto? Se estiver facilita as coisas...

Comment: Sim é Jquery! Obrigado

Comment: Vou ter que colocar na resposta, pois é um bloco de código. Estou editando ela.